# Finding the nearest element in a 2D Numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a two-dimensional numpy array like:

```
 [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

We can think of it as a map that is viewed from above.
I'll pick a random cell, let's say line 3 column 4 (start counting at 0). If the cell contains a 1, there is no problem. If the cell is a 0, **I need to find the index of the nearest 1.**

Here, line 3 column 4 is a 0, I want a way to find the nearest 1 which is line 4 column 5.

- If two cells containing 1 are at the same distance, I don't care which one I get.
- Borders are not inter-connected, i.e. the nearest 1 for the cell line 7 column 9 is not the 1 line 7 column 0

Of course it is a simplified example of my problem, my actual np arrays do not contain zeros and ones but rather Nones and floats

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. 
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple "path-finding" problem. Prepare an empty queue of coordinates and push a starting position to the queue. Then, pop the first element from the queue and check location and if it's 1 return the coordinates, otherwise push all neighbours to the queue and repeat.

```py
ADJACENT = [(0, 1), (1, 0), (0, -1), (-1, 0)]

def find(data: np.array, start: tuple):
  queue = deque()
  deque.append(start)
  while queue:
    pos = queue.popleft()
    if data[pos[0], pos[1]]:
      return position
    else:
      for dxy in ADJACENT:
        (x, y) = (pos[0] + dxy[0], pos[1], dxy[1])
        if x >= 0 and x < data.size[0] and y >= and y < data.size[1]:
          queue.append((x,y))
  return None
```

Comment: Thank you, do you have an idea for a simple way not to include positions that are at the opposite of the map when the start point is close to a border ?

Comment: You can do if statements checking if next position's x and y are within the board size